# Playwright/test: How to authenticate with storageState after base page is loaded using fixtures?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-test

I have faced with a problem and don't understand how to resolve it I'm building UI test solution with Playwright and Playwright/test. The goal is to authenticate with help of storageState

So, what I have for now

1. global-setup.ts runs from Playwright.config as precondition and saves storageState.json file.
2. Next step I'm using fixtures in order to initialize some data e.g. Pages, services

[image]

3. In the test itself, I'm using test.use({storageState: 'storageState.json'}) and it works as expected. Navigates to expected page

[image]

4. But, in my case the problem is we have a service uploads some data to browsers and logged out user.

So, I'm wondering if I can set storageState after navigation to base page and some timeout to load data. The problem is page is isolated, because I'm using Fixtures.

Any idea's how it can be resolved?